# Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) return "Program Files (x86)"

Tags: vb.net

I have a VB application which tries to read a file from the users AppData folder which the installer puts the there.

On most machines, this works perfectly, but on one user's machine the call to

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

is returning "Program Files (x86)" instead of "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming"

When I use Windows Explorer and ask for %AppData% I get the right folder.

Probably related: the installer, which is a Visual Studio Setup project, didn't write to the the AppData folder, either.

Could this be a registry problem? Residue from an old installer? Any ideas?

Comment: What you get for `Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData`?

Comment: I didn't try that. This is an installed application that I was doing phone support for (with the help of a SysAdmin at the client's PC). So I didn't get a chance to play around too much.